# Using MySql to populate a html table using a specific column

Tags: php, mysql, database

Essentially, I am creating a movie ordering system that has 7 movie genres, and I want each movie tab to populate according to genre. At this point I cant even get the table to show up. Can anyone help me out?

```
    <div id="content">
    <table>
    <tr><th>Name</th> <th>Genre</th> <th>Year</th> <th>Rating</th></tr>
<?php
//connect to database
$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost' , 'username' , 'password');
$test = mysql_select_db('movies', $dbc);

if ($test = mysql_select_db('movies', $dbc))//test
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM 'movies' WHERE 'genre' = 'Action'";

    //call query
    $result = mysql_query($query, $dbc);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        ?>

        <tr>
        <td><?php print $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $row['genre']; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $row['year']; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $row['rating'];?></td>
        </tr>
<table>

        <?php

    }//close the while loop

}//close the if statement

mysql_close($dbc);

?>
```

Comment: You're probably getting a mysql error. Add or die(mysql_error()) to the end of your mysql statements like so: $result = mysql_query($query, $dbc) or die (mysql_error());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do not use  mysql because of  secure problems and it will be not suported in PHP later. Read about this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php .

Try to use PDO or mysqli, for example :

```
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM 'movies' WHERE 'genre' = 'Action'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['name'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your response!